# lsb_release: command not found in latest Ubuntu Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, containers, version

I just wanted to test something out real quick. So I ran a docker container and I wanted to check which version I was running:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu    
root@471bdb08b11a:/# lsb_release -a
bash: lsb_release: command not found
root@471bdb08b11a:/#
```

So I tried installing it (as [suggested here](http://www.andryhacks.com/bash-lsb_release-command-not-found/)):

```
root@471bdb08b11a:/# apt install lsb_release
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lsb_release
root@471bdb08b11a:/#
```

Anybody any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: the command is `lsb_release` (with underscore) but the package to install is `lsb-release` (with an hyphen)

Comment: @RubenLaguna i wonder who thought it is a good idea to have two different names...

Answer (score 262, accepted):

It seems `lsb_release` is not installed.

You can install it via:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release && apt-get clean all
```

Comment: I only needed to install the package `lsb-release`. `lsb-core` works too, but it brings in a whole bunch of dependencies I don't need.

Comment: This is why I love Linux - black magic resulting in several screens of output just to see OS version!

Comment: @AlexanderChristov you can just run `uname --all` for kernel version or `cat /etc/os-release` for distribution info, if you don't want to do it the recommended way

Comment: I guess is worth noting that the command is `lsb_release` (with underscore) but the package to install is `lsb-release` (with hyphen)

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 27):

Just use `cat /etc/os-release` and that should display the OS details.

Screenshot from debian.

[image]

Screenshot from ubuntu.

[image]

Screenshot from fedora.

[image]

Comment: You can consider adding the output as text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 6):

This error can happen due to uninstalling or upgrading the default python3 program version in ubuntu 16.04

The way to correct this is by reinstalling the original python3 version which comes with ubuntu and relinking again. (in ubuntu 16.04 - the default python3 version is python 3.5

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: It's advised to be careful changing the potential symlinks in `/usr/bin/python3`. You really should be using `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 35 #or whatever priority.` That being said, mine is there, but the shebang is for **python**, not **python3**
(I parsed @DeadlyChambers' comment for better readability. You could even consider posting it as an answer instead.)

Comment: @Cadoiz you are probably right, I should post this as an answer to hopefully save one poor soul from the hell that awaits them when they start tinkering with system python configurations the wrong way. This is how you end up chasing dependency ghosts, and updating libraries to fix the initial mistake. Then before you know it, random things just stop working.

Answer (score 2):

`lsb_release.py` lives in `/usr/share/pyshared` which to me doesn't look like python3.6 and above is referencing.

I found the following will create a link back from a later Python install to this `/usr/share` script:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lsb_release.py
```

Answer (score 1):

In case one is trying to deal with `lsb_release: command not found` on fedora or redhat, the package to install is redhat-lsb-core , so `sudo dnf install redhat-lsb-core`

Answer (score 0):

While writing Dockerfile we can add lsb-release package - like this

```
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install lsb-release -y \
    && apt-get clean all
```

Assuming OS is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

if you run docker build

you can try

```
sudo service docker restart
```