# lsb-release has no installation candidate while trying to install on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

After trying many different command, the lsb-release is always not being able to be installed.
Tried `sudo apt-get update -y` and `sudo apt-get install -y lsb-release`, it gives the package missing error:
[image]

Could anyone have any advice on how we can install this package?

Comment: please don't post images of text. Copy paste the commands and their output and format them accordingly.

Comment: yes commands and outputs already posted

Comment: @user3651247 Are you using Kaspersky?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58395655/5272567 this seems to work well if anyone runs into this now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my machine:

```
 $ apt policy lsb-release 
lsb-release:
  Installed: 11.1.0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 11.1.0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 11.1.0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The package `lsb-release` comes from the repository `main`. The output of `sudo apt update` suggests that you've missing sources in your `sources.list` file.

To investigate further, I started a new docker container and disabled all instances of the `main` repository and I was able to reproduce this issue. You can fix this issue by following the below steps:

1. You must enable the `main` repository in order to install the package `lsb-release`:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository main
   ```

   I highly recommend you to enable the Universe repository too:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   ```
2. Run `apt update` after enabling the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. If I'm seeing the output correctly, you have one more issue with the package manager, as stated in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1124335/1460940) remove the offending files with:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
   ```
4. Install `lsb-release` again:

   ```
   sudo apt install lsb-release
   ```

The package `lsb-release` should be installed now.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have tried your suggestion but looks like `add-apt-repository` not being recognized due to missing some package. Therefore, I am trying to install the package 'sofware-properties-common' but same issue 'has no installation candidate' occurred. I also tried to change my /etc/apt/sources.list file to cover all resources based on the link 'https://gist.github.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170'. However the 'has no installation candidate' still exist. This is same issue when I am trying to install npm `sudo apt install npm`.

Comment: Looks like the above command cannot not be run successfully, which due to the verification issue 'ERROR: cannot verify gist.githubusercontent.com's certificate'