# lsb_release: command not found on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, lsb

Hello I'm trying to install postgreSQL on Ubuntu 20.04, but when I exexute the very first command in order to create file repository configuration:

`$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'`

I get `bash: lsb_release: command not found`.

It might be useful to point out that I uninstalled `Python 3.6.0` and then I installed `Python 3.8.5` before postgresql so I think that this could be the reason of the hassle.

Here I post some commands and its outputs I executed that can help for a better understanding of the actual problem.

***sudo apt-cache policy lsb-release***

```
lsb-release:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidates:  (none)
  Version Table:
     11.1.0ubuntu2 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

***sudo apt-get install lsb-release***

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package lsb-release is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package "lsb-release" does not have a candidate for installation
```

***lsb_release***

```
bash: lsb_release: command not found
```

Please let me know if I should provide further information that might be useful in order to figure out what's the origin of the issue.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo apt install lsb-release` or `sudo apt install lsb-core`.

I think a quick search might have saved.

Edit:

1. You could try installing via the `.deb` file which can be downloaded from [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lsb-release)
2. I believe the lsb_release package might still exists on your system but it's somehow no longer in PATH
3. Find lsb_release(usually in `usr/bin`) and then symlink. You can refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71332054/13534779)

Sorry for my first answer.

Comment: This is what I get after executing ***sudo apt install lsb-core***:
```Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The lsb-core package is not available, but some other package references
to it. This may mean that the package is missing, out of date, or only
is available from some other source
E: Package "lsb-core" does not have a candidate for installation
```

Comment: If the OP already states that he tried to use `apt install`, there's no need to write an answer telling him to repeat that

Comment: That first one was a mistake, moreover the second command should work.

Comment: Then please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.

Comment: No worries for your previous answer, I think that you are right regarding your edit. I execute the following command ***sudo dpkg -S lsb_release*** to check if there are any executables and this is the output ```apparmor: /etc/apparmor.d/lsb_release```. I feel like somehow it still exists and that's why I cannot install it executing ***sudo apt install lsb-release/lsb-core*** . It would be interesting to completely remove it before trying to reinstall it by means of the `.deb` file you provided at step 1 or even the regular install.

Comment: Btw I don't have neither */usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py* nor */usr/bin/lsb_release* within my folder structure

Comment: Well i think you should just reinstall it, you could try `sudo apt reinstall lsb-release`

Comment: Reinstalling removes missing dependencies from previous installation?

Comment: The following files persist `base-files: /etc/lsb-release` `apparmor: /etc/apparmor.d/lsb_release`

Comment: `base-file: etc/lsb-release` shouldn't cause any problem since it just contains your system info but i don't know about apparmor