# Can't create environment with conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I'm trying to create environment with command: `conda create --name env_name python=3.6`, but after running the command there is written this error message:

```
Retrieving notices: ...working... failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/session.py", line 75, in __call__
        return cls._thread_local.session
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'session'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 64, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, parser)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 167, in do_call
        result = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 108, in wrapper
        channel_notice_set = retrieve_notices(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 40, in retrieve_notices
        channel_notice_responses = fetch.get_notice_responses(
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/notices/fetch.py", line 39, in get_notice_responses
        return tuple(
               ^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/notices/fetch.py", line 42, in <genexpr>
        (
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 619, in result_iterator
        yield _result_or_cancel(fs.pop())
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 317, in _result_or_cancel
        return fut.result(timeout)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 456, in result
        return self.__get_result()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/notices/fetch.py", line 45, in <lambda>
        lambda args: get_channel_notice_response(*args), url_and_names
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/notices/cache.py", line 36, in wrapper
        return_value = func(url, name)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/notices/fetch.py", line 59, in get_channel_notice_response
        session = CondaSession()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/session.py", line 77, in __call__
        session = cls._thread_local.session = super().__call__()
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/session.py", line 114, in __init__
        self.headers["User-Agent"] = context.user_agent
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 267, in new_fget
        cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconda_anon_usage/patch.py", line 15, in _new_user_agent
        result = ctx._old_user_agent
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 267, in new_fget
        cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 965, in user_agent
        builder.append("%s/%s" % self.os_distribution_name_version)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/auxlib/decorators.py", line 267, in new_fget
        cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 1036, in os_distribution_name_version
        from conda._vendor.distro import id, version
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 1080, in <module>
        _distro = LinuxDistribution()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 595, in __init__
        self._lsb_release_info = self._get_lsb_release_info() \
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/mypc/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/_vendor/distro.py", line 939, in _get_lsb_release_info
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout, stderr)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1.

`$ /home/mypc/anaconda3/bin/conda create --name env_name python=3.6`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/home/mypc/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/mypc/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/mypc/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/mypc/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 INFOPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:
               LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
                  MANPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:
                     PATH=/home/mypc/anaconda3/bin:/home/mypc/anaconda3/condabin:/home/mypc/.car
                          go/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:
                          /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/game
                          s:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/mypc/Desktop/Uni/III-Course/Paradig
                          ms/kawa-
                          3.1.1/bin:/usr/local/go/bin~/anaconda3/bin:/home/mypc/.local/share/Jet
                          Brains/Toolbox/scripts:/home/mypc/Desktop/Uni/III-
                          Course/Paradigms/kawa-3.1.1/bin:/usr/local/go/bin~/anaconda3/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
               WINDOWPATH=2

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/mypc/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/mypc/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/mypc/.condarc
          conda version : 23.7.4
    conda-build version : 3.26.1
         python version : 3.11.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __cuda=11.4=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __linux=5.15.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /home/mypc/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/mypc/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/mypc/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/mypc/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/mypc/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/mypc/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/23.7.4 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.5 Linux/5.15.0-89-generic Linux/unknown glibc/2.31 aau/0.4.2 c/B6SyoPMszXXqCTva49ft-g s/rBcUO9kaVexPNGLtULrFlg e/3hk3fTlJQyWB2Da7RYZaeQ
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.

Example: conda --no-plugins install <package>

Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on
the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.

Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install <package>

Upload successful.
```

I looked for this kind of error and some people advice to install requests==2.8.1... I've tried it but there is same error. Can you suggest some solutions?
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58395566/570918 I.e., looks like the system command `lsb_release` isn't found on PATH and AFAIK, that isn't something Conda can provide. Also, [here is a GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/13336) on this error (looks like it is fixed in more recent Conda releases, e.g., `23.11`).

Comment: lsb_release is probably installed because 
after executing command 'lsb_release' there is written this message:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lsb_release'
"

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've fixed this problem by this way:

- Open `/usr/bin/lsb_release` file
- Change first line from `#!/usr/bin/python3 -Es`  to `#!/usr/bin/python3.6 -Es`
- Save the file